Institutional approach to linear algebra
In Diaconescu's book Institution Independent Model Theory, it is mentioned on p. 37 that linear algebra can be viewed as an institution. Specifically, we have the following

Definition. An institution $\mathbb{I}$ consists of the following:

A category $$\mathbb{S}ig$$ of whose objects are called signatures, denoted $\Sigma$.
A functor $${\sf Sen}:\mathbb{S}ig\to{\bf Set}$$ assigning to each signature $\Sigma$ a set ${\sf Sen}(\Sigma)$ whose members are called sentences over $\Sigma$.
A functor $${\sf Mod}:\mathbb{S}ig^{op}\to\mathcal{Cat}$$ assigning to each signature $\Sigma$ a category ${\sf Mod}(\Sigma)$ whose objects are called $\Sigma$-models, and whose arrows are called $\Sigma$-model homomorphisms.
A natural transformation $$\models:{\sf Mod}\Rightarrow{\sf Sen}$$ called satisfaction whose components are relations $$\models_\Sigma\subseteq{\bf Ob}_{{\sf Mod}(\Sigma)}\times{\sf Sen}(\Sigma)$$ and where naturality is called the satisfaction condition.


We have play around with ${\sf Sen}$ and ${\sf Mod}$ to get satisfaction to be a natural transformation (take the 'object part functor' of ${\sf Mod}$, extend both functors into ${\bf Rel}$, transpose one) but the details work out. Linear algebra forms an institution as follows:

We define an institution $\mathbb{L}in\mathbb{A}lg$ whose category of signatures is $\mathbb{C}Rng$, the category of commutative rings, where the category of models of a commutative ring $R$ is ${\bf R-Mod}$, the category of $R$-modules, the set of sentences assigned to $R$ is the set of all linear systems of equations with coefficients in $R$, and satisfaction is defined by the existence of solutions to these systems of linear equations.

Does anyone have a reference fleshing out this view on linear algebra? Any pointers are appreciated.
